# How to divide string in two parts?

Tags: c, string

I need to write a program where the user inputs 3 items and their relative prices, on three separates strings. Then I have to check whether the last item and price are the same as one of the other two. If that is the case I have to print the item and the total price (the price of that item multiplied by 2).

The problem is that apparently when I call a function to divide the name of the item from the price (I would ideally save them as two separate strings, and then convert the float string of the price to a normal float variable), but it doesn't work.

This is the function

```
void f(char v[], char product[], char price[]){

int i=0, a=0, inword=0, z=0;

while (!z) {
    if(isalpha(v[i])&&inword)
        product[i]=v[i];
    if (isalpha(v[i])&&!inword) {
        inword++;
        product[i]=v[i];
    }
    if (isspace(v[i])&&inword) {
        inword=0;
        a=1;
    }
    if ((isdigit(v[i])||v[i]=='.')&&a) {
        price[i]=v[i];
    }
    if (a&&v[i]=='\n')
        z=1;
    i++;
}
puts(product);
puts(price);
```

}

I made sure it is properly defined in the main and before the main. 
The input string should be something like this:
`Apple 4.99\n`
Therefore I first search for a letter, if I find one I start to save the word in the string product, then as soon as I find a space I exit from "inword" and I search for a digit (the price doesn't have € £ or $).

Ideally the outcome of the two strings would be:

product = `Apple`
price = `4.99`

But if I try to print the price it's empty...
Can you help me?

The side question is how do I search for £ $ € in the string? If I write '€' it gives me an error sign...
Thank you for your help

Comment: Code uses `product`, `price` as _stirngs_, yet does not append a null character to either.

Comment: Research `strtok()`.  Something like `strcpy(product, strtok(ch, " \n")); strcpy(price, strtok(NULL, " \n"));` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this

```
void f(char v[], char product[], char price[]){
    char * p = v;
    while (!isdigit(p[0]))
        p++;

    memcpy(product, v, p-v);
    product[p-v]='\0';
    strcpy(price, p);
}
```

Comment: Thank you... This worked and was a more elegant solution! I didn't know there were were command like these!